# Printing multiple lines in a file?

Tags: python, file, printing

Ok, well, i am trying to make a little program that asks you to enter a file name and it will create the file with the name you wanted. in that File it will display the adult price and the children price on two different lines. Anyone?

```
packagename = input("Enter package name:")
packagepriceadult = input ("Enter package price per adult:")
packagepricechild = input("Enter package price per child:")
a = open ("output.txt", "a")
a.write (packagename),"\n"
a.write (packagepriceadult)
a.write (packagepricechild)
```

Comment: 1. what language is this? Python? 2. What is your question? Is there an error? What is the error?

Comment: I tried alot of things like: a.write ((packagename)\n) but that wont work

Comment: i want python to create a .txt file. and in that text file i want it to print the(packagepriceadult) and the (packagepricechild) in two different lines

Answer (score 1):

Another option available in python 2.x is to redirect the print statement to the file

```
print >>a, packagename
print >>a, packagepriceadult
print >>a, packagepricechild
```

See this post more info - [slippens's blog](http://stefaanlippens.net/redirect_python_print)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the linebreak to the file, for example:

```
a.write(packagename)
a.write("\n")
a.write(packagepriceadult)
a.write("\n")
a.write(packagepricechild)
```

Comment: And don't forget to close the file with a.close().

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python 2.x you can also do like I've done here:

`outlist = [packagename, packagepriceadult, packagepricechild]
a.write('\n'.join(outlist))`